# How to sort a list/stream using an unknown number of comparators?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have the following snippet:

```
List<O> os = new ArrayList<>();
os.add(new O("A", 3, "x"));
os.add(new O("A", 2, "y"));
os.add(new O("B", 1, "z"));

Comparator<O> byA = Comparator.comparing(O::getA);
Comparator<O> byB = Comparator.comparing(O::getB);

// I want to use rather this...    
List<Comparator<O>> comparators = new ArrayList<>();
comparators.add(byA);
comparators.add(byB);

os.stream()
    .sorted(byB.thenComparing(byA))
    .forEach(o -> System.out.println(o.getC()));
```

As you can see, I sort using explicitly two comparators. But what if I have the unknown number of comparators in some list and I want to sort by them all? Is there any way? Or should rather use the old fashion way comparator with multiple ifs?

Comment: It might be better to have `O` implement `Comparable` so you can just use `Stream.sorted()`, unless you're using more than one sorting method (or can't alter the `O` class).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have multiple comparators in a list or any other collection, you can replace them with a single one by performing the reduction on a `Stream`:

```
List<Comparator<String>> comparators = ...

Comparator<String> combined = comparators.stream()
  .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
  .orElse(someDefaultComparator); // empty list case
```

All instances will be composed together using `thenComparing` according to their order from the input list.

---

The same would be achievable using a non-stream approach by utilizing a simple for-loop:

```
Comparator<String> result = comparators.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < comparators.size(); i++) {
    result = result.thenComparing(comparators.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This is nice and clean but Comparator::naturalOrder doesn't fit. It's of type T.

Comment: @JiKra here comes the very important question, how do you want to handle an empty list scenario? The whole point is here to remember about the edge case of passing in an empty list - obviously `naturalOrder` will not work for all scenarios

Comment: There wouldn’t be any problem performing the reduction in parallel, as combining comparators is an associative function. But it’s very unlikely that the list of comparators ever has a size that justifies performing this reduction in parallel.

Comment: You can use `.orElseGet((a,b) -> 0)` to get a comparator that works with every type and simply doesn’t change the order.

Comment: @pivovarit I think I can stay with some default comparator that I will have prepared.

Answer (score 6):

You can `reduce` stream of comparators to a single comparator by calling `.thenComparing()` on accumulated comparator and current comparator in the iteration:

```
Optional<Comparator<O>> comparator = Optional.ofNullable(comparators.stream()
    .reduce(null, (acc, current) -> acc == null ? current : acc.thenComparing(current), (a, b) -> a));

os.stream()
    .sorted(comparator.orElse((a,b) -> 0))
    .forEach(o -> System.out.println(o.getC()));
```

In this example I use `Optional<Comparator<O>>` and wrap reduction result with `Optional.ofNullable()` to handle a case when with empty comparators list. Then you can decide when you pass a result to `sorted()` method what to do in case of an empty list - you can use `(a,b)->0` comparator that does not sort anything.

Then it doesn't matter how many comparators you want to apply. But there is one **but** - the order of comparators in given collection matters. In given example I apply comparators in ascending order (starting from the first element of the list to the last one). It affects the result of sorting heavily.

For example, in your example you call `byB.thenComparing(byA)`. It produces different result then `byA.thenComparing(byB)`. I can assume that in some cases you want to control the order in which comparators are applied.

Live demo:

> https://jdoodle.com/a/4Xz

Comment: I don't understand the null identity. And from the other hand, if list is empty, it throws NPE.

Comment: I supposed you mixed thing up a little. `(a, b) -> 0` is the comparator that doesn’t affect the order (for all stable sort operations), whereas `(a,b) -> 1` is broken.

Comment: And, of course `(a, b) -> a` is a broken combiner as it simply drops the `b` comparator chain. It should be simply `thenComparing`, but since the functions are identical, you can just use `reduce(null, (acc, current) -> acc.thenComparing(current))`, or even better `reduce((acc, current) -> acc.thenComparing(current))` which returns an `Optional`, so there is no need to deal with `null` at all…

Comment: Totally agree, this is something I've learned today thanks to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use google guava, you could simply compound your Comparables.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound-java.lang.Iterable-

Comparator comparator = Ordering.compound(comparators);

If no comparators are given, the original order will be kept.

Javadoc of guava on this method although proposes for Java 8:

```
list.stream().sorted(comparators.stream().reduce(defaultComparator, Comparator::thenComparing));
```

So the solution with 'compound' is recommended for Java 7 (or less).